# authenticating with username and password from database which created using asp.net mvc

Tags: windows, model-view-controller

i have already created database on mvc website which i authenticate userdatata(username and password) using asp.net identity, you know the password is hashed in the database , now i have windows application and this application wants to authenticate with the same database username and password, how can i authenticate with the hashed password as i cant use applicationsigninmanager or such controllers in my windows app , i tried to construct UserManager and the other user in mvc but i couldnot manage to do it

Answer (score 0):

You could always implement an OAuth2 authorization flow for use in your api using OWIN middleware. That way both the MVC app and the Windows App could benefit from the same authentication mechanism. Some details [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/aspnet/overview/owin-and-katana/owin-oauth-20-authorization-server).

Comment: thanks for your answer,but plz i have windows application that will authenticate so i dont have http context  to access the database, the only problem that i am facing is when registering ..the password must be hashed the same why that mvc using and when logging the authentication method shall hash the password and compare with the stored hashed password , sorry i am new to this technology but confused

Comment: I doubt that the Windows app should be responsible for hashing the password. You should ideally have one registration mechanism (that may use multiple hashing methods) that can be consumed either directly or via some service (like over Http). This is probably a bigger question than someone could answer in something like StackOverflow. Try heading to the [ASP.NET Forums](https://forums.asp.net/) to have a more in depth conversation.